# Is there a way to spread data evenly among multiple mongodb collections?

Tags: mongodb

Recently, i’ve been using mongo and i have a microservices architecture.
I have 5 instances of the same microservice and i want each one of them to read from a different mongodb collection. However, each one of these collections should contain the same data, such that when i insert more data into the db it will be inserted to the collection using the least resources.
Is there a way to configure mongo collections to act in that way on data insertion? (it is critical that i don't use sharding but spread the documents among these collections).

Comment: can you elaborate what you're trying to solve? load balancing and replication can be configured to be handled by the DB so the application does not need to consider it.

Comment: Ill try my best. I have 5 instances of a microservice, each one of them is acts as the deployments container. I want each one of these deployment instances to consume from these 5 mongo collections. It is crucial that one deployment doesn’t get a single datapoint that another one got. At the end of the day these instances deal with the same type of data so i need to find a way to distribute it among them. Load balancing is irrelevant because it is within mongo/the instances whereas i need the data to not only be distributed evenly, but rather uniquely.

Comment: Also, i fetch this data from mongo every once in a while and resend it to these instances, so i need each instance that consumes it to be the only consumer of that datapoint

Comment: is there any logic requirement to determine which service get's what data? if a data point is fetched for how long can it not be touched by other services? is there any pre-known data distribution that we can use? can you provide the schema of the data?

Comment: There is no such logic. If it is fetched it can never be touched by another instance. Im not sure about the third question but i do know the environment is not sharded. Unfortunately i cannot give you a schema as it might be changed but you can assume one datapoint consists of a name, description and a numeric field (you can add more fields if it solves the problem)

Comment: If it is fetched it can never be touched by another instance.
what happens if the service "dies"?

Comment: Than a reset mechanism of data redistribution will be activated. For the time it is living the same datapoint cannot be processed by the same microservice instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the following assumptions ( as discussed in the comments ):

- Once a service access an data point it belongs to that service forever
- If a service dies an external triggers "resets" the diribution

I promise the following approach:

A. We need to generate a unique identifier for each service, this can either be injected from the environment, for example an incremental number indicating the number of the service (which would be my recommendation ). Or an easier approach that will require to integration is to generated a `guid` in the memory of the service.

B. when your service needs to fetch a data point, instead of using `findOne` to get it, we'll use `findOneAndUpdate` with the following query:

```
const serviceUniqueIdentifier = uniqueValue;
db.collection.findOneAndUpdate(
  {
    ...documentQuery,
    $or: [
      {
        unique_identifier: {$exists: false}
      },
      {
        unique_identifier: serviceUniqueIdentifier
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    $set: {
      unique_identifier: serviceUniqueIdentifier,
      last_touched: new Date()
    }
  }
)
```

Basically anywhere you're trying to access documents we should use this query, and update their `unique_identifier` field. Because Mongo's `findOneAndUpdate` is atomic this ensures only this service will use this data point.

---

When you want to "reset" the system you'll need to `$unset` all the `unique_identifier` fields, if you inject the `unique_identifier` value you could keep existing distribution if you're happy with it.

---

I am not aware how your services echo system works, but in theory all data points could be assigned to a single service.